# React router location only updated in some components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Whether using links or `this.props.history.push()`, URL in the address bar is updating correctly, as well as `this.props.location` in a component which is higher up the DOM tree (in this case, my `App` component).

However, for some reason it is not updating `this.props.location` in my components which are further down the tree, which is causing my routes to fail.

Any guesses on what could be going wrong?

NOTE: I am using redux in this project, but I'm not changing the `this.props.history` using redux, at least for now. I don't think this should impact anything, but if it is , let me know

edit: Here is the relevant portion of the DOM tree (with my email carefully scratched out) if it's helpful. As you can see, the `Authenticated` component has an outdated `this.props.location` (`/plans`), whereas the `App` is correct (`/posts`). Both are wrapped in withRouter. Components further down the tree than `Authenticated` also have the wrong location.

[image]

Comment: Question about the failing components: Are they connected to redux or is `this.props.location` passed down from its parent?

Comment: @Andrew the components are wrapped in `withRouter`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are likely dealing with [blocked updates](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md). Luckily, it's not hard to solve:

> If you are running into this issue while using a higher-order component like `connect` (from react-redux), you can just wrap that component in a `withRouter` to remove the blocked updates.
>
> ```
> // before
> const MyConnectedComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)
> // after
> const MyConnectedComponent = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent))
> ```

Comment: I have definitely made of mistake before, but it isn't the problem in this case. The component which doesn't update is wrapped in `withRouter`, and does have this.props.location as a prop. In fact, if I refresh the page, now that the URL bar is being updated, the correct `this.props.location` is passed in

Comment: It is kind of hard to see, but I added a picture for clarification

Comment: It's likely the same issue, just higher up the tree (probably at `Connect(User)`). The `Route` component doesn't do any magic global change listening; if _anything_ higher in the tree returns false for `shouldComponentUpdate`, re-rendering won't happen.

Comment: @AlexGuerra so basically you need to wrap everything in `withRouter` all the way down the tree to the lowest branch that needs the `props.location`?

Comment: Well, because there's no magic yeah you need to propagate the location change down to anything that uses `shouldComponentUpdate` and who's contend depends on location. react-redux's `connect` implements scu by default, and it doesn't "know" about the location change unless its told via a prop. `withRouter` is a convenience so you don't need to _manually_ propogate `location` down the whole tree, but it's kind of deceptive because you still need to avoid skipping updates through the whole tree.

Comment: I stand corrected :) Classic case of forgetting the fundamentals. Thanks for both of your help

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was a mistake in js entry point. My code was:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App/>                       // <- missing Route!
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

And I fixed it by adding `<Route/>`:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Route component={App}/>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```